# filling a textarea with ng-repeat or ng-model so that it does not create a new textarea one on top of the other with the iterated data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

im having issues trying to fill a single 10 row textarea with data using ng-repeat instead it creates a new textarea for every data entry. how can i just insert into one? and i would like to make the size of the textarea dynamic to the number of entries enterd by ng-repeat

this is my js file

```
var WaitingRequisitionsController = function($scope, $rootScope, $modal, $window, items) {
    $rootScope.title = 'Direct Requisitions';
    $scope.items = items;

    $scope.formatDate = function (x) {
        return moment(x).format("M/D/YYYY");
    };
};
```

and this is my html file, specifically the area im trying to insert.

```
  <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Items</label>
              <div ng-repeat="item in req.items">
                  <textarea ng-model="item.description" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

and this does the same thing

```
  <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Items</label>
              <textarea ng-repeat="item in req.items" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly">{{item.description}}</textarea>    
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

i have changed my js to look like this

```
var WaitingRequisitionsController = function($scope, $rootScope, $modal, $window, items) {
$rootScope.title = 'Direct Requisitions';
//$scope.items = items;




$scope.formatDate = function (x) {
    return moment(x).format("M/D/YYYY");
   };
};

function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = items.join('\n');
  $scope.$watch('items', function (items) {
    $scope.myArray = items.split('\n');
    console.log('$scope.myArray', $scope.myArray);

 });



  }
```

and my html to look like this

```
            <!-- <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
        <div class="form-group" ng-app>
        <label>Items</label>-->
        <div ng-app>
            <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
                <textarea rows={{rows}}  class="form-control" ng-model="myStr" type="text" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
               <!-- </div>
            </div>
        </div>-->
```

but nothing populates if i change this around to look like this
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8165/

it works..i dont get it
i need item.description i dont know if that has anything to do with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Join the items into a single string, separated by newlines

```
var WaitingRequisitionsController = function($scope, $rootScope, $modal, $window, items) {

    $rootScope.title = 'Direct Requisitions';

    $scope.items = items
        .map(function (item) {
            return item.description;
        })
        .join('\n');

    $scope.rows = items.length;

    $scope.formatDate = function (x) {
        return moment(x).format("M/D/YYYY");
    };

};
```

You can then use the length of the items array to set the number or rows on the text area.

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-controler readonly="readonly" rows="rows"
          ng-model="items">
</textarea>
```

Plunker for example: http://plnkr.co/edit/SXSl4nHJi8ptufP6wTd4?p=preview

Comment: this looks great but i cant adjust mine so that it comes out right.  im 2 weeks into my angular learning

Comment: my JS file doesnt look modularized like the example on plnkr either. and i dont have ng-app or ng-controller declared on my body tag, hell i dont  even have a body tag

Comment: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide is a good reference for how to modularize your code

Comment: i messed with it some more and i edit my post so i can show you what i did. and i add my source for change. still doesnt work. i need items.description not hardcoded array

Comment: You can use map on your array do only return the description. I have updated the plunker as well as the sample code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

You're ng-repeating `<textarea>` (either in itself, or through a containing `div`) so that it iterates over each instance of `item`.  What you need to do is get rid of the `ng-repeat` all together and use `ng-model` to concatenate a string, as demonstrated in [ajs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34298271/393219)'s answer.

Comment: i tried it that way and nothing populates.i need the description part of those objects.

Comment: i messed with it some more and i edit my post so i can show you what i did. and i add my source for change. still doesnt work. i need items.description not hardcoded array.